# Extract rows and save to multiple csv files using shell

Tags: shell, csv

I am trying to extract data from a CSV file and save it to multiple CSV files using Shell, I am new to shell and tried the below code but I am getting "unterminated 'y' command error ". please help me with this i dont know where i am wrong?

```
m=344
x=1
i=100
y=1
while [ $i -lt $m ]
do
sed -n '$y,$ip' test1.csv > $x.csv
i=$(( i + 100 ))
y=$(( y + 100 ))
x=$(( x + 1 ))
```

done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In shell variables are not expanded/interpreted inside single quotes. See below example.

```
jmaster:~$ echo $var # this works, as shell understand $var as variable
Hello World
jmaster:~$ echo '$var' # inside single quote, shell doesn't treat $ as special
$var
jmaster:~$ echo "$var" # works in double quotes
Hello World
```

In your case you have used variables $y and $i inside single which obviously wont get expanded. Use double quotes there.

```
sed -n "${y}, ${i}p" test1.csv > $x.csv # this works
sed -n "$y, $ip" test1.csv > $x.csv # this won't work, as shell consider "ip" as variable
sed -n "$y, $i p" test1.csv > $x.csv # this too work, I hope
```

Its better to understand shell quotes before playaround with shell. unless its hard to interpret the errors.

Comment: @vik55, I am glad it works. If you find this gives you necessary information, you can accept this as answer to the post.